# FB.init Fails, throwing non-stop xd_arbiter.php errors

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

After I call FB.init, this error is repeatedly getting sent to my console and never stopping.

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://domain.com/index.php/tms/updateprofile from frame with URL http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=9#cb=f2c537d51c&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Ff292b6c658&domain=domain.com&relation=parent&frame=f151cd576c&code=2.AQD5022tv7g5YP9h.3600.1343304000.5-809735726%7CRK1BKSccupfslgdlXkXL_5TJgiU&signed_request=RTIhluTQhwrHRBNdI3hPLrzMZ8kh-J3M3_Y73AH0BAE.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiIyLkFRRDUwMjJ0djdnNVlQOWguMzYwMC4xMzQzMzA0MDAwLjUtODA5NzM1NzI2fGZNSjJTdWZST25Wa2RnSEdWWldVUFN6NmhJcyIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTM0MzI5NzA1NywidXNlcl9pZCI6IjgwOTczNTcyNiJ9&access_token=AAAFOhEfCjnQBAJSZAFyZBrLZBckHoGOqdPM2jn1Q0wpfNPVFGFTzMxUZBsBo9wWVNOYFlfe0ovLtpHWZCnuXUCZATJcGhRMPRzlFddQ0XZBagZDZD&expires_in=6943&https=1. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is expected?

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/122268321247958

Comment: Yes, the error is expected, but I think Colin may also wondering why the errors don't stop.